# How can I find a root node in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView in my Windows application. Tn this TreeView, the user can add some root nodes and also some sub nodes for these root nodes and also some sub nodes for these sub nodes and so on ...

For example:

```
Root1
     A
       B
         C
         D
          E  
Root2
     F
      G
.
.
.
```

Now my question is that if I am at node 'E' what is the best way to find its first root node ('Root1')?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a little method for you:

```
private TreeNode FindRootNode(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    while (treeNode.Parent != null)
    {
        treeNode = treeNode.Parent;
    }
    return treeNode;
}
```

you can call in your code like this:

```
var rootNode = FindRootNode(currentTreeNode);
```

Comment: thanks Fischermaen,so treeview does not have any property to find the root node of a sub node,it does?

Comment: it's much better to cach the root during the population.

Comment: @Dmitry: Thank you for mentioning that. Caching the root value has some disadvantages: you have to track every change (when you put nodes to other places) and you have to add a management object containing data object and root node. Was my answer that bad, that you had to downvote it?

Comment: I thought an MS treeview had only one root, and it was accessible via the .topnode property

Answer (score 0):

```
public TreeNode RootTreeNode(TreeNode n) { while (n.Level > 0) { n = n.Parent; } return n; }
```

Example to get root treenode:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    var node = (e == null ? ((System.Windows.Forms.TreeView)sender).SelectedNode : e.Node);
    var rootNode = RootTreeNode(node);
}
```

Enjoy